# List Index Out of Range in Python; Iteration

Tags: python

I am using the simple program below to see how long an iterative process takes to terminate. However, in line 15, I cannot figure out why I am getting index out range error.

An example of what I am trying to count is the number of steps it takes for the following example iteration: User inputs 4 and then 1234. Then we have: [1,2,3,4] --> [1,1,1,1] --> [0,0,0,0] and then termination. 2 steps is required to get to [0,0,0,0]. I have proven that for the values of n that I am inserting, the system goes to [0,0,0,0] eventually.

```
import math
index = input("Enter length: ")
n = int(index)
game = input("Enter Coordinates of length n as a number: ")
s = list(game)
Game = []
for k in s:
    Game.append(int(k))
    l = len(game)
while sum(Game) > 0:
    Iteration = []
    k = 0
    j = 0
    while j < l-1:
        Iteration.append(math.fabs(Game[j]-Game[j+1])) # line 15
        j = j+1
        k = k+1
        Game = Iteration
print(k)
```

Comment: `Game = Iteration` is probably why. When j = 1, Game will be a list with only one item because of that. Then, Game[1]-Game[2] will be out of bounds.

Comment: Oh I see why! I am not adding all of the terms I want in Iteration. Thanks!

Comment: I wrote as an answer. If this solved your problem, please mark as correct! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Game = Iteration` is probably why. When j = 1, Game will be a list with only one item because of that. Then, Game[1]-Game[2] will be out of bounds.

Comment: In other words, the `list` variable `Game` is getting shorter on every pass, but he fails to account for this by changing `l`; [more details in my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25587962/20789).

Answer (score 1):

Your code is written in a very un-[Pythonic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(programming_language)#Features_and_philosophy) style that suggests you're translating directly from C code. (Also, you should basically never use `input()`; it's insecure because it evaluates arbitrarily user-entered Python code! Use `raw_input()` instead.)

If you rewrite it in a more Pythonic style, it becomes clear what the problem is:

```
import math

# you don't do anything with this value, but okay
s = index = int(raw_input("Enter length: "))

# game/Game naming will lead to confusion in longer code
game = raw_input("Enter Coordinates of length n as a list of comma-separated numbers: ")
Game = [int(k) for k in game.split(',')]
l = len(Game)

while sum(Game) > 0:
    Game = [math.fabs(Game[j]-Game[j+1]) for j in range(l-1)] # problem here

# no idea what k is for, but it's not used in the loop anywhere
```

The problem is that in every iteration through your inner `while` loop, or the line marked `# problem here` in my version, your `Game` list gets shorter by one element! So on the second time through the outer `while` loop, it reads an element past the end of `Game`.

I have no idea what this code is trying to do, so I can't really suggest a fix, but if you truly intend to shorten the list on every pass, then you of course need to account for its shorter length by putting `l=len(Game)` inside the `while` loop.